# How do I combine a string and a variable into one command and execute it in bash?

Tags: bash

To get into detail, I am writing a shell script to automate usage of a plugin.
To do so, I am using xclip to pull a url from the x clipboard, then append it at the end of a command with arguments and execute the combined command.

I use `url="$(xclip -o)"` to get the url from the clipboard, then `com='youtube-dl -x --audio-format mp3 '` to set the initial string.
I've been clumsily stumbling through attempts at `printf` and defining new strings as `str=$com $url` (and many variants of such. I haven't written anything in a long time and know I'm screwing up something pretty basic. Anybody able to help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to concatenate two strings with a space in an assignment

```
str=$com' '$url
```

can be also written

```
str=$com" "$url
```

or

```
str="$com $url"
```

then the command can just be launched

```
$str
```

however

```
str=$com $url
```

is the syntax to call $url passing environment variable str=$com

also if url was a string which could contains spaces or tabs anan array should be used instead to avoid splitting when called

```
str=( $com "$url" )
"{str[@]}"
```

Comment: I really suggest replacing `' '` with `--` . The `--` signals the end of options and disables further option processing . In this case the immediate use case is not visible. But consider a script that takes a filename argument and the filename starts with a `-`.  The array too is a clean way of doing it I believe. `:-)`